# Copy& Paste Fedora and Virtualbox CentOS7

Tags: centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, clipboard

I want copy text from Fedora 21 and paste to Virtual box with CentOS 7
how can I do that??

I change in Virtual box settings Shared Clipboard and Drag'n'Drop to bidirectional 
[image: Virtual Box Settings]

Thanks for help, Michael.

Comment: What I do for stuff like that is leave the VM running and use Putty to SSH into the VM. This will allow you to do highlight copying.

Comment: Did you already install [guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for me:
Right click on virtual machine -> setting -> networking and change

```
 Attached to: Bridged Adapter
```

[image: VirtualBox Networking]

After change the setting do command `shutdown -h now` in your virtual machine.

hint: (`ip addr` help to find ip address).
At now your can ssh to virtual machine (from your terminal host machine).

Thanks for help.

Comment: just a note, `shutdown -h now` = `poweroff`

Comment: This works for VirtualBox on the Mac too. Crazy that VirtualBox doesn't work better 'out of the box'.